# How do i make a proper "nuke" command discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Okay i want to make a "nuke" command that basically saves the old name, topic and permissions, deletes the channel and add it back with the same permissions, name and topic. How do i do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you ask a question, generally you need to back it up with some code, or an attempt. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/how-to-ask).

Comment: first write some code and come back when you get error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [discord.py API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel) defines the various properties and methods one may manipulate for a Discord Channel. Rather than hard-coding this, I would recommend using the [`clone()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel.clone) method, which, given a channel,

> *Clones this channel. This creates a channel with the same properties as this channel.*

At that point, you may simply delete the old channel via [`delete()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel.delete).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that I use, hope it helps

```
@client.command()
async def nuke(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel = None):
    if channel == None: 
        await ctx.send("You did not mention a channel!")
        return

    nuke_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=channel.name)

    if nuke_channel is not None:
        new_channel = await nuke_channel.clone(reason="Has been Nuked!")
        await nuke_channel.delete()
        await new_channel.send("THIS CHANNEL HAS BEEN NUKED!")
        await ctx.send("Nuked the Channel sucessfully!")

    else:
        await ctx.send(f"No channel named {channel.name} was found!")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the command

```
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@client.command
async def nuke():
```

Answer (score -1):

just use mee6 and !delete [number of messages to be deleted]

Comment: Please check for typos, use https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and add an explanation by [edit]ing your post.